# I can't open mdf file in Visual Studio 2008 - file open like txt file and not in managament studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, mdf

I have Visual Studio 2008 and ASP.NET MVC2 project. To App_data folder I added ContactManager.mdf file (Add existing item). Now I try this file to add tables to this database. But when I double-click this file it open like txt file:
cŔ>xň›G0- ...
And it should open in editor which looks like Management Studio when I can create tables in Visual Studio without open MS SQL Management Studio.
I thik that I must install any application but I don't know which.
I have full version Visual Studio 2008.

---

When I get right-click on App_data then Add new item and select SQL Server database and click Add messagebox with error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object is showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mdf file is not readable as is. You have to "mount" the MDF file in a running instance of Sql Server, either under sql service, or user instance (easiest in VS).

After that, you can open the DB using the connection manager window of VS. VS will automatically find the db in the app_data folder and provide a ready to use connection to it.

Comment: Yes I know that is not readable. Mdf file is mounted in Sql Server (2008 R2). But I still cannot open this file. I cannot create new db file from Visual Studio by clicking Add new item -> Data -> Sql Server Database

Answer (score 2):

I always use "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express" for managing MS SQL database services instances and database files. With it you are able to log on to your sql instance and mount (or restore) the mdf file to a database.

The application is from Microsoft and is free! http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8961

Answer (score 0):

In the server explorer window (top-left of vs 2008) can you see the database? If yes, right click on the table and add new.  I suspect there is a problem with your vs installation

Comment: I don't know where is server explorer window, when I select Data from top menu and then Show Data Sources Visual does nothing and this same is when I select Data -> Add new data source...

Comment: When I select View -> Server Explorer Visual does nothing

Answer (score 0):

try to open it from visual studio environment from any new application 
go to view->other windows->database explorer which will appear in the left side.
then click on new connection , the menue that will be appeared containing brows then select your database that you want to add tables and whatever......